# How do I make my dwarves smooth and round?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I want to use [this font used by DF Wiki](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2014:Tilesets#What_tiles_are_used_for_what) as a tileset. For example, dwarves should look like this:

[image]

Smooth and round, instead of the bearded version in the default tileset, i.e. `curses_800x600.png`.

I had a glance at DF Wiki's [tileset repository](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/Tileset_repository), and found nothing similar.
Is there an existing tileset for this purpose, or should I disable the tileset and specify some font instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using [Lazy Newb Pack](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/Utility:Lazy_Newb_Pack), the current version has various options which seem to meet your needs. These are found under `Graphics`, `Customize`.
curses_square_24x24.png
[image]
DejaVu-font.png
[image]
Taffer20x20_Sans_HSWalls.png
[image]

I also checked [Tileset Repository](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/Tileset_repository) for large square tilesets, as are necessary to have smooth circles. Hack_square_64x64.png might be the best. Sample in game, and full tileset included below.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't mean this. I just want my dwarves seem round and smooth, but not necessarily use "vanilla" Code Page 437. It's my bad.

Comment: @SunQingyao Updated my answer, hope it helps

Comment: Thanks. In fact I've tried `Hack_square_64x64.png` before I asking this question, but it failed without error messages: the df window didn't even pop up (I'm playing vanilla df under macOS). Maybe I should post another question on that issue.

Comment: @SunQingyao That might be best. It worked for me, but I'm on windows, with LNP. Vanilla may not support the dimensions of the set.